# Convert objective C code to C#

Tags: c#, objective-c

i came across some Objective C code as follows

```
-(void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterLabel:(UILabel *)label forDatapoint: (SChartDataPoint *)datapoint atSliceIndex:(int)index inRadialSeries:(SChartRadialSeries*)series// End
```

I want to convert it to C# for use in Xamarin. I havent been able to try as I dont know any objective C.

What would be the equivalent C# code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have code to convert, I think it would be a good idea to know both languages.

Comment: i am not porting code, it sporadic code.

Comment: That's not really code. It's a method declaration.

Comment: i know, still code in my opinion and i am looking for its C# equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just grab and use an Objective-C library with Xamarin/C#. To use 3rd party native Objective-C code with Xamarin, you need to have bindings available for that library or you need to create bindings by yourself.

When creating binding you have luxury to decide how your C# equivalent code is going to look like. Though it should resemble original Objective-C library as much as possible while keeping in mind C# coding conventions and best practices.

Here is more info about creating Xamarin bindings for an Objective-C library.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/